# What is the meaning of "subject {page}" in Rspec and Ruby Language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm reading the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)", and on a page regarding to Rspec tests, there is this line:

```
subject {page}
```

We can `omit` the word from, for example:

```
it { page.should have_content('Help') }
```

What is `subject`? What is `page`?

Also, why is it declared `subject{}` and `it{}`? I saw that the braces ("{}"), are used when you are declaring a hash like:

```
user = {name: 'Jhon', lastName: 'Smith'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code can make it more clear:

Say you have a class:

```
class A
  def initialize(m, n)
    @m = m
    @n = n
  end

  def m
    @m
  end

  def n
    @n
  end
end
```

Than to test that method `m` returns the correct value you can use this code with subject:

```
subject { A.new("lorem", "ipsum") }
specify { subject.m.should == "lorem" }
specify { subject.n.should == "ipsum" }
```

In the example above `subject` will be the object that you created in `subject { A.new("lorem", "ipsum") }`.

Or you can use code like this to make the rspec examples shorter:

```
subject { A.new("lorem", "ipsum") }
its(:n) { should == "lorem" }
its(:m) { should == "ipsum" }
```

And the `page` in your post was just an object which was created somewhere else in the code of the test.

Answer (score 4):

`subject` is an [rspec method](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/explicit-subject) that takes a block which will be the implicit topic of your assertions. `page` refers to (probably) [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)'s `page` object, which is available in rspec tests using Capybara where you have done something like [`visit('/some/url')`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#visit-instance_method).

Comment: Actually, it's the _implicit_ subject. :-) You can still specify an explicit subject with each assertion or use the variable `subject` explicitly.